# With the Dawnguard installed is there any negative effect for the the stage 4 vampirism?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

When going into fourth stage of vampirism I see the message:

> As a Blood-Starved Vampire, you are hated and feared

But the only change I see is the slightly worse Weakness to Fire / Sunlight. I know that without the Dawnguard dlc 4th stage vampires were attacked on sight and that was removed but since I still get the warning I was wondering if there are any hidden negative effects, disposition penalty or anything like that ?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism#Active_Effects_and_Abilities) site, the only negative effect is weakness to sunlight,

> Weakness to Sunlight
>   While outside during the day, health, magicka, and stamina are reduced, and the regeneration for each of these stats is reduced by 100%. The reduction increases with each stage of vampirism, as indicated in the table above. Day begins at 5am and ends at 7pm regardless of the visibility of the sun.

, but the rest of the effects seem positive for example:

> Nightstalker's Footsteps
>   A permanent active effect you gain from stage one onward that makes you 25% harder to detect while sneaking.

There is a total of seven positive effects, and abilities.

And by effect, I mean the abilities that are permanent.